# how to highlight entire <DIV> </DIV> in Vim?

Tags: html, vim

I am using the latest Vim in Ubuntu and Vimrc by Vincent Driessen of nvie.com.
How do I highlight the entire section between matching pair of div and /div? The DIV tag on the same line is highlighted when I am on < of the DIV tag, but I want to highlight the entire section, to see if divs are matched all over the page, one by one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Move to the starting `<div>` tag, then hit <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.